Export Word laravel
public function ExportWord($id)
{
    $client = Demanderendezvous::findOrFail($id);

    $customData = [];
    foreach ($client->getAttributes() as $key => $value) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'created_at':
                $key = 'Date Pris rendez-vous';
                $value = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($value));
                break;
            case 'updated_at':
            case 'etat':
            case 'Id_agent':
            case 'id':
                continue 2;
        }
        $customData[$key] = $value;
    }

    $phpWord = new PhpWord();
    $section = $phpWord->addSection();

    foreach ($customData as $key => $value) {
        $section->addText("$key: $value");
    }
    $filename = $client->Prenom . '_'.$client->Nom . '_' . $client->Num_RDV . '.docx';
    $path = storage_path('app/public/' . $filename);
    $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save($path);
    return response()->download($path)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
}

in this code i want to export data from table but i dont know how can add style to the document
$boldFontStyle = array('bold' => true);
$italicFontStyle = array('italic' => true);

$section = $phpWord->addSection();

foreach ($customData as $key => $value) {
    // Add key with bold style
    $section->addText("$key: ", null, $boldFontStyle);
    // Add value with italic style
    $section->addText($value, null, $italicFontStyle);
    // Add a new line for separation
    $section->addTextBreak(1);
}

i try this but it didnt work

Looks like the second parameter to addText is the one to apply the font style, and the third parameter looks to be for paragraph style, neither of those styles are available for paragraph.
